# Angular Routing Issues ( Router Not registering clicks)

Tags: angular, routes, angular-lazyloading

I am stuck and would be thankful for your help.

I am new to Angular and using the Lazy loading approach to load modules.
I have a master Module with a routing module that holds all the children routing with it. as follows

**--- Main Routing  Aggregator Module ---**

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("../../views/home/home.module").then((m) => m.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: "personalisation",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("../../views/personalisation/personalisation.module").then(
        (m) => m.PersonalisationModule
      ),
  },
  {
    path: "weddingcollection",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("../../views/wedding-collection/wedding-collection.module").then(
        (m) => m.WeddingCollectionModule
      ),
  },
  {
    path: "weddingservice",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("../../views/wedding-service/wedding-service.module").then(
        (m) => m.WeddingServiceModule
      ),
  },
  {
    path: "designerperfumes",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("../../views/designer-perfumes/designer-perfumes.module").then(
        (m) => m.DesignerPerfumesModule
      ),
  },
  {
    path: "shop",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("../../views/shop/shop.module").then((m) => m.ShopModule),
  },
  {
    path: "spotlight",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("../../views/blog/blog.module").then((m) => m.BlogModule),
  },

  {
    path: "spotlight/:id",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("../../views/single-blog-page/single-blog-page.module").then(
        (m) => m.SingleBlogPageModule
      ),
  },

  {
    path: "addblog",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("../../views/add-blog/add-blog.module").then(
        (m) => m.AddBlogModule
      ),
  },

  {
    path: "**",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("../../views/page-not-found/page-not-found.module").then(
        (m) => m.PageNotFoundModule
      ),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class MasterRoutingModule {}
```

Similarly, Each component/module stack have their own routing module as follows

**---- Individual Module with Routing definition---**

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { BlogComponent } from "./blog.component";

const routes: Routes = [{ path: "", component: BlogComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class BlogRoutingModule {}
```

**--- component Where User links are Hard coded ----**

```html
<div id="sideMenuitems" class="sidenav-item">
  <a [routerLink]="['']">
    <h4 class="text-uppercase">Home</h4>
  </a>

  <a [routerLink]="['/personalisation']">
    <h4>Personalisation</h4>
  </a>

  <a [routerLink]="['/shop'] ">
    <h4 class="text-uppercase">Shop</h4>
  </a>

  <a [routerLink]="['/weddingcollection']">
    <h4 class="text-uppercase">Wedding Collection</h4>
  </a>

  <a [routerLink]="['/designerperfumes']">
    <h4 class="text-uppercase">Designer Perfumes</h4>
  </a>

  <a [routerLink]="['/weddingservice']">
    <h4 class="text-uppercase">Wedding Service</h4>
  </a>

  <a [routerLink]="['/spotlight']">
    <h4 class="text-uppercase">Spotlight</h4>
  </a>
</div>
```

The problem:

When I click on the links some times (50% of the times) the click doesn't register the change to the routing.  the screen goes blank and, upon the inspection, the URL remains unchanged.

e.g. Say, the user is on the blog (spotlight) page now and clicks on the shop page.

1. The screen becomes blank,
2. The URL still says /spotlight as opposed to /shop.
3. The user then Clicks on a different link say /designerperfumes
4. Screen loads designer perfume component and all is well
5. the user now clicks back on the shop link  - Screen loads the shop page now.

This happens 50% of the time in all the 3 (Chrome, Safari and Firefox Browsers). I am unable to figure out what's going on as I have a basic understanding of Angular Routing and  Lazy loading.

Can you please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when displaying a blank screen?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mario, you are a genius. I had completely ignored to look at the error log.  Rookie mistake on my part, I had defined subscriptions handlers but didn't assign them to a subscribe function, but then I was trying to unsubscribe them later during NgDestroy ().  It was throwing errors there, have fixed it and given it a quick run and seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have structure issues, you can use "Augury" chrome extension to see in browser your app router-tree. Check if modules aren`t importing in two places.